# Как определить что это целое слово?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеется код где я из линии получаю строку которую надо заменить.
Далее эту строку я передаю в regex функцию.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(oldName);
text = rgx.Replace(text, newName);
```

Как мне определить что oldName это целая строка ? Иначе он тупо заменяет все слова где присутствует oldName. А мне нужно только чтоб oldName было целым словом а не входило в другое.

Я думаю надо как-то определить что слева и справа слова oldName нет других букв ?

Comment: `\b` может и не сработать в зависимости от того, на какие символы начинается и заканчивается `oldName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

```
/\b(work)\b/ig
```

```js
// заменить слово "work" в любых регистрах на "REST"
var a = "The work anworkd the carpenter, Work,";
var oldStr = "work";
var newStr = "REST";
var re = new RegExp(`\\b(${oldStr})\\b`, "ig");
var b = a.replace(re, newStr);
console.log(b);
```

C#:

```
string a = "The work anworkd the carpenter, Work,";
string oldStr = "work";
string newStr = "REST";
Regex re = new Regex(@"\b(" + oldStr + @")\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string b = re.Replace(a, newStr);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Comment: не работает. Вставил вашу регулярку и ничего.
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"/\b("+oldName+@")\b/ig");
text = rgx.Replace(text, newName);