# Почему регулярное выражение возвращает слово с лишними символами?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

[image: Скриншот с regex10]

```
/[^а-яёА-ЯЁa-zA-Z0-9_]qwe[^а-яёА-ЯЁa-zA-Z0-9_]/ui

<br>qwe<div>
```

Comment: я добавил регулярное выражение, а текст не вставляется (режет теги)

Comment: @aleksandr barakin спасибо

Comment: Используйте `/\bqwe\b/ui`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как определить что это целое слово?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909944/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [^а-яёА-ЯЁa-zA-Z0-9_]
```

Ищет один символ, не входящий в перечисленные здесь. `^` в начале означает искать то, что не входит в перечисленное. Здесь не перечислены `<>`, поэтому он их учитывает в поиске.
Чтобы здесь найти qwe, достаточно просто шаблона `qwe` . Ну или выделить в этом шаблоне группу `/[^а-яёА-ЯЁa-zA-Z0-9_](qwe)[^а-яёА-ЯЁa-zA-Z0-9_]/ui`